# Multiple filters with relation on Prisma 2

Tags: node.js, apollo-server, prisma

I would like to know how can I use multiple filter with Prisma 2 when almsot one filter is an relation. I search one post with specific ID and specific author (security reason).

I read the [documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-client/filtering) and I try to apply with this :

```
const postExists = await prisma.post.findMany({
    where: {
        AND: [
            {
                id: {
                    equals: parseInt(args.id, 10), // args.id => 770 
                },
            },
            {
                author: {
                    id: {
                        equals: parseInt(userId, 10), // userId => 584
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
})
```

In my database I have this :

[image]

But I found my post if I'm not the author (for example, author id 1)

```
const postExists = await prisma.post.findMany({
    where: {
        AND: [
            {
                id: {
                    equals: parseInt(args.id, 10), // args.id => 770 
                },
            },
            {
                author: {
                    id: {
                        equals: parseInt(userId, 10), // userId => 1
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
})
```

In my schema.prisma I have this :

```
model Post {
  content    String?
  createdAt  DateTime @default(now())
  fk_user_id Int
  id         Int      @default(autoincrement()) @id
  published  Boolean  @default(false)
  title      String
  author     User     @relation(fields: [fk_user_id], references: [id])

  @@index([fk_user_id], name: "fk_user_id")
}

model User {
  email    String   @unique
  id       Int      @default(autoincrement()) @id
  name     String?
  password String   @default("")
  Post     Post[]
  Profile  Profile?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Relation Fields

Your second filter should be with `fk_user_id` instead of `author`.

The fields `author` and `posts` are virtual fields in `Post` and `User` respectively. They are called *relation fields*. The relation fields define connections between models at the Prisma level and they do not exist in the actual database tables.

It's the `fk_user_id` that represents the author (`User`) who created the `Post`.

Also, since in your case, you'll always get a single `Post` as a result, use `findFirst()` instead of `findMany()`. This way, you won't have to deal with an `Array`.

---

### Using Multiple Filters

Here's is the rectified code:

```
const postExists = await prisma.post.findFirst({
    where: {
        AND: [
            {
                id: {
                    equals: parseInt(args.id, 10) 
                }
            },
            {
                fk_user_id: {
                    equals: parseInt(userId, 10)
                }
            },
        ],
    },
})
```

Notice that we removed two levels `author:` and `id:` and inserted just one level `fk_user_id:`. We also removed unnecessary commas.